# trying to get element value by index with elementTree function in lxml no output

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

```
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r"D:\General\Python_Preference_validation\sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
root[0][1].text
```

Here is the `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I am expecting to get output as 2008 but when I run the script it does not providing any output nor complaining about any syntax error. pasted a code and xml as well

Comment: xml to be validated is present in location of some directory.

Comment: Tested locally and it works fine. What happen if you try this: `for r in root: print r`?

Comment: @floatingpurr for loop gives me <Element 'country' at 0x000001CDAF0A9048>
<Element 'country' at 0x000001CDAF54F8B8>
<Element 'country' at 0x000001CDAF557B38> I want simple flat list of all year elements for compare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have just to `print`

```
print root[0][1].text # output '2008'
```